# max weight on code and current weight not changing and staying equal on a hx711 load cell attached to an lcd

Tags: c++, arduino

I am building a hx711-based weight scale that displays the measured weight on an LCD, along with the weight the LCD shows a "max weight" If weight>max weight the buzzer will buzz. I have written code to perform these functions but, the weight always goes to zero no matter what and I cant set the max weight. I will include a schematic and the code here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CC6Jy.jpg

```
#include "HX711.h"
#include <Wire.h>


#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);

int IN1 = A0;

int IN2 = A1;

int over_val;
int data;
int g_weight;
int Weight;

const int buzzer = 13;


void setup()
{
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  lcd.init();
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.backlight();
  pinMode(IN1, INPUT);
  pinMode(IN2, INPUT);
  Init_Hx711();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Ready!\n");
  Get_Maopi();
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(" Harry Brass ");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("  Gus Creech  ");
  delay(1000);
  lcd.clear();
}

void loop()
{

  Weight = Get_Weight();
  g_weight = Weight - data;

  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Weight:");
  lcd.print(g_weight);
  lcd.print("g    ");

  if (digitalRead(IN2) == LOW) {data = Weight;}
  if (digitalRead(IN1) == LOW) {over_val = g_weight;
  }

  if (g_weight <= over_val)
  {
    lcd.setCursor ( 0, 1 );
    lcd.print("Max Weight:");
    lcd.print(over_val);
    lcd.print("g    ");
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
  }

  else if (g_weight > over_val)
  {
    Serial.println("overload");
    lcd.setCursor ( 0, 1 );
    lcd.print("...OverLoad!!...");
    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
  }

  delay(50);
}
```

Comment: You should probably at least zero initialize your variables. It looks to me like you’re using `data` without actually assigning it a value. So it is garbage data. Could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would start from checking the physical connections and trying to run a simple code like this: https://www.instructables.com/Arduino-Scale-With-5kg-Load-Cell-and-HX711-Amplifi/ .
Just to make sure everything is working fine.

Comment: alright i did that and its working, in my code the wiehgt constantly reverts back to zero no matter what. any ideas?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).